# REGEX: Add semicolon between email addresses in list string

Tags: regex, notepad++

Im trying to create a REGEX with Notepad++ that will look at a string of email addresses, find the emails that are not separated by a semicolon, and then add one in between the emails that do not. Here's an example:

```
johnsmith@yahoo.comtravissmith@yahoo.com;joy@yahoo.com
troy@yahoo.comben@yahoo.comterry@yahoo.com;barry@gmail.comhorace@yahoo.com
greg@timewarner.comallen@ford.com
```

Thanks ahead of time.

Comment: And what have you tried so far?

Comment: oh, not that easy job for regex. you can tell what a email is but computer does not.

Comment: Not possible. Given that ICANN is producing new TLDs faster than bacteria reproduce, there's no easy to way tell where one address ends and a new one starts. e.g. `.comtravvissmith` might be `.comtravis;smith...` or some other wonky combination. or eve `.co;mtravisssmith`, given that `.co` is columbia.

Comment: Ok thanks for the comments. I was using ".com[a-Z]" to search but my replace value of ".com;" was replacing characters in the email. So a@a.comb@b.com would become a@a.com;@b.com. I think I can use my search still but not sure what to use in the replace. Any ideas?

Comment: So, how do I insert a semicolon in my string with Replace?

Comment: You can use something like `\.com(?=[a-zA-Z])` and replace with `.com;` to achieve that (note: `[a-Z]` is not the same thing as `[a-zA-Z]`).

Comment: Excellent. Thats exactly what I needed. Thank you! Add your answer and I'll give you credit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use your current regex with some slight modifications:

```
\.com(?=[a-zA-Z])
```

And replace with `.com;`.

`(?= ... )` is called a positive lookahead. It kind of works like your current regex except that the things in it do not form part of the match. This thus only makes sure that your match is followed by what's inside the positive lookahead.

Secondly, it mightn't make much of a difference, but `[a-Z]` is not the same as `[a-zA-Z]` if you case case sensitive matching. `a-Z` first isn't a valid range (`A-z` would be however, and contains `[`, `\`, `]`, `^`, `_`, `` ` ``). So, to be on the safe side, I would recommend using `[a-zA-Z]`.

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is probably just to replace ".com"  with  ".com;". Unless you have strangely-formatted emails, it should catch most of them without false positives.